# How to Instantiate a new JSONObject programmatically with an incremental value in its name

Tags: java, android, json

I have a form where I'm collecting vehicle information. (i.e. registration number, make and model, year of purchase and estimated value). Below this I have a button "Add another" that enables a user to add the details of another vehicle. The user can add an infinite number of vehicles. Whenever a user taps on the "Add another" button, I will  get the details in the form and store in a JSONObject. The problem is that I do not know how many vehicles a user will add, so I cannot instantiate the JSONObject before hand. I need this to be done when the user clicks on the "Add Another" button. I would also like for the JSONObject name to have a standard name with an incremental value at its end (e.g. vehicle_details1, vehicle_details2, vehicle_details3 ....) to enable easy processing by the script that receives it.

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should only be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it.

Answer (score 1):

**You should use a JSONArray**

You have a JSONArray that contains all of your cars (each car is a JSONObject)

```
JSONArray cars = new JSONArray();
...

private void addCar(Car car, JSONArray carList){
    JSONObject carJson = new JSONObject();
    //if you still want an id name
    String id = "vehicle_details" + (carList.length() + 1);
    carJson.put("id", id);
    carJson.put("registration number", car.getRegistration());
    carJson.put("maker", car.getMaker());
    ...

    carList.put(carJson);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to add the try/catch block for JSONException

Comment: The variable being passed to the function, 
private void addCar (Car car, ...
what is its use?